# Rename [steamplay] to [steam-play]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Can we rename the [steamplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steamplay) tag to [steam-play](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-play)?

The official name of this feature is [Steam Play](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9439-QHKN-1308), and the hyphenated tag will fit in with the various other Steam feature tags (e.g. [steam-workshop](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-workshop)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makes sense to me. I've completed this.